# What is the difference between applying CSS transition property in hover rather than in its normal state?

Tags: css

I'm learning CSS3. Now, what I've seen in w3schools website is that:

**CSS**

```
#ID {
  transition: transform 3s;
}

#ID:hover {
  transform: rotateX(20deg);
}
```

And what I did is this:

**CSS:**

```
#ID:hover {
  transform: rotateX(20deg);
  transition: transform 3s;
}
```

Both are working. So, the **question** is: Can I put both transition and any transformation property in same selector? Or is it not the right way?

Comment: The first example is generally correct, as the transition timing is stated on the unaffected state. But that's based on the majority of examples I've seen of how to generate transitions on hover actions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**SHORT ANSWER:**

If you define your `transition` property in `element:hover`, it will **only** get applied in that state.

---

**EXPLANATION:**

Whichever CSS properties you define in `element:hover` will **only** be applied when the element is in the hover state, whereas whichever CSS properties you define in your `element` will be applied in **both** states.

---

***Transition property declared in normal state:***

See how the transition always runs when the element's state is changed. When you stop hovering the element it will still make the transition back to its normal state.

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```css
#ID {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: royalblue;
  transition: transform 1s;
}
#ID:hover {
  transform: rotateX(60deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="ID"></div>
```

---

***Transition property declared in hovered state:***

See how the transition breaks when you stop hovering the element and it jumps to its normal state immediately.

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```css
#ID {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: royalblue;
}
#ID:hover {
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform: rotateX(60deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="ID"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first example is generally correct, as the transition timing is stated on the unaffected state. But that's based on the majority of examples I've seen of how to generate transitions on hover actions.

Answer (score 0):

**1st case :**

All your transition in the `#ID` will have a transition of 3s.
When you hover your #ID, your transformation is `rotateX(20deg)`.

**2nd case :**

When you hover your `#ID`, you have a transition of 3s.

**Overall :**

All the transitions from the first css will have a duration of 3s. Then you can apply transitions on your `#ID` from different places. Whereas in your second case you separate them and if you want to have another transitions triggerd by something else than hover, you will have to specify the duration again.

Both are correct

Answer (score 0):

When a transition is specified for the `:hover` state, the transition won’t work on mouse out.