# transition on link's 'hover-off' not animating

Tags: html, css

I have a button with a transition on hover

css

```
.main-nav li a {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
padding: 12px 10px;
}

.main-nav li a:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
background-color: #d11e5d;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 3px; width: 0;
bottom: 3px; left: 0; right: 0;
}

.main-nav li a:hover { color: #d11e5d; }
.main-nav li a:hover:after { width: 80%; }

/* other links */ .main-nav li a:hover, .main-nav li a:hover:after {
transition: width 0.2s ease, color 0.35s ease, background-color 0.35s ease, border 0.35s ease; 
-webkit-transition: width 0.2s ease, color 0.35s ease, background-color 0.35s ease, border 0.35s ease;
-moz-transition: width 0.2s ease, color 0.35s ease, background-color 0.35s ease, border 0.35s ease;
-ms-transition: width 0.2s ease, color 0.35s ease, background-color 0.35s ease, border 0.35s ease;
-o-transition: width 0.2s ease, color 0.35s ease, background-color 0.35s ease, border 0.35s ease;
}
```

html (generated from bootstrap/Wordpress)

```
<div class="main-nav">
   <ul class="menu">
      <li>
       <a href="..."> ... </a>
```

The after element animates in properly, but doesn't animate out (just stops abruptly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the `transition` property in your `:hover` state.

Change this:

```
...other links... , .main-nav li a:hover, .main-nav li a:hover:after {
transition: width 0.2s ease, color 0.35s ease, background-color 0.35s ease, border 0.35s ease; 
-webkit-transition: width 0.2s ease, color 0.35s ease, background-color 0.35s ease, border 0.35s ease;
-moz-transition: width 0.2s ease, color 0.35s ease, background-color 0.35s ease, border 0.35s ease;
-ms-transition: width 0.2s ease, color 0.35s ease, background-color 0.35s ease, border 0.35s ease;
-o-transition: width 0.2s ease, color 0.35s ease, background-color 0.35s ease, border 0.35s ease;
}
```

To this:

```
...other links... , .main-nav li a, .main-nav li a:after {
-webkit-transition: width 0.2s ease, color 0.35s ease, background-color 0.35s ease, border 0.35s ease;
-moz-transition: width 0.2s ease, color 0.35s ease, background-color 0.35s ease, border 0.35s ease;
-ms-transition: width 0.2s ease, color 0.35s ease, background-color 0.35s ease, border 0.35s ease;
-o-transition: width 0.2s ease, color 0.35s ease, background-color 0.35s ease, border 0.35s ease;
transition: width 0.2s ease, color 0.35s ease, background-color 0.35s ease, border 0.35s ease; 
}
```

---

If you're wondering **what is the difference between applying CSS transition property in hover rather than in its normal state**, you can check [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38226397/what-is-the-difference-between-applying-css-transition-property-in-hover-rather/38226571#38226571).

---

Notes:

- Always make sure the property without vendor prefixes is placed
  **below** the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I see some issues in the last CSS block:

```
...other links... , .main-nav li a:hover, .main-nav li a:hover:after {
transition: width 0.2s ease, color 0.35s ease, background-color 0.35s ease, border 0.35s ease; 
-webkit-transition: width 0.2s ease, color 0.35s ease, background-color 0.35s ease, border 0.35s ease;
-moz-transition: width 0.2s ease, color 0.35s ease, background-color 0.35s ease, border 0.35s ease;
-ms-transition: width 0.2s ease, color 0.35s ease, background-color 0.35s ease, border 0.35s ease;
-o-transition: width 0.2s ease, color 0.35s ease, background-color 0.35s ease, border 0.35s ease;
}
```

As a minor fix, I'll point out that the vendor prefixed `transition` properties should always precede the "standardized" CSS property. In other words, order the unprefixed `transition` style to be last following those for `-webkit-`, `-moz-`, `-ms-` and `-o-`. See this response [SO answer to prefix ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7080674/4608094).

I notice you include the `.main-nav li a:hover:after` CSS selector. If this is what you're using to try and effect a CSS transition when hovering off, it won't work. The `:after` pseudo-element is not for this usage. Rather, what you want is to apply the transition styles you declared on `.main-nav li a`. Notice I didn't include the `:hover` pseudo-element. That's intentional. This way, I'm saying "*I want to transition these properties (width, background-color & border) when I DO hover onto the selected element"*. Then, apply the different `width`, `background-color` and `border` CSS styles on the `.main-nav li a:hover` element separately. These will be the property styles that get transitioned **to** once you hover over the link. You'll notice that when you hover over the link now, the styles transition as desired.

If you're also trying to apply a secondary transition when hovering off the link, you'll have to apply those styles separately for the `.main-nav li a:hover` selector. Additionally, you would then declare a `transition` property on the `.main-nav li a:hover` selector. As it stands now, you have the same transition being applied to both the `.main-nav li a` and `.main-nav li a:hover` selectors (which is technically fine, just maybe not what you wanted). See this post [Different Transitions for Hover On/Off](https://css-tricks.com/different-transitions-for-hover-on-hover-off/)

```css
.main-nav li a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  font: bold 3rem/2 Fantasy, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 12px 10px;
}

/* .main-nav li a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #d11e5d;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 3px; width: 0;
  bottom: 3px; left: 0; right: 0;
} */

.main-nav li a:hover {
  width: 50%;
  color: #d11e5d;
  background-color: Yellow;
  font: lighter 5rem/3 cursive, serif;
}
.main-nav li a:hover:after { width: 80%; }

/* ...other links */
.main-nav li a {
  -webkit-transition: width 0.2s ease, color 0.35s ease, background-color 0.35s ease, border 0.35s ease;
  -moz-transition: width 0.2s ease, color 0.35s ease, background-color 0.35s ease, border 0.35s ease;
  -ms-transition: width 0.2s ease, color 0.35s ease, background-color 0.35s ease, border 0.35s ease;
  -o-transition: width 0.2s ease, color 0.35s ease, background-color 0.35s ease, border 0.35s ease;
  transition: width 0.2s ease, color 0.35s ease, background-color 0.35s ease, border 0.35s ease;
}

.main-nav li a:hover {
  -webkit-transition: font 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: font 0.2s linear;
  -ms-transition: font 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition:font 0.2s linear;
  transition: font 0.2s linear;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main-nav">
   <ul class="menu">
      <li>
        <a href="..."> ... </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Last, I'm assuming the `...other links` text is intended as a comment. If so, that should be commented-out appropriately, `/* Other links */`, and can potentially cause issues.

Comment: Ok, yes it was meant to be a comment, so i'll fix that.  The problem is I want to animate the element created with :after, aside from color it is the one growing/shrinking. I have a button used already which works exactly as I wanted, but I can't tell why this one doesn't